# Div not showing on change in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I want to hide an option in my form unless a specific option is selected but my coffee script doesn't seem to work. It looks like:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.input.boolean.optional').hide()
  selected = $('#stand_type :selected').text()
  value = "Microphone"
  $('#stand_type').change ->
      $('.input.boolean.optional').show() if selected is value
```

This code compiles correctly. Yes I am aware of the IDs and class selectors, they are different in the code as I'm using simple_form which only gives a div a class this is why when hiding it I'm using a class not an ID. The [html for my form looks like](http://pastebin.com/jVyts5V8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in your script is wrong. Your checking for the value before its updated so it will always be empty your script should look like this:

```
jQuery ->
  $('.input.boolean.optional').hide()
  value = "Microphone"
  $('#stand_type').change ->
    selected = $('#stand_type :selected').text()
    $('.input.boolean.optional').show() if selected is value
```